# If I leave brie in my fridge for two weeks, will it still taste as good?

Tags: cheese, brie

Can you refrigerate Brie cheese for about two weeks unopened and expect it to still be as good? I have a round of it and it does not smell or anything. I kept it at a certain temp.

Comment: What is "at a certain temp"? And how does the title relate to the question at all?

Comment: The only warning I saw on cheese in France was on a refrigerated piece that advised that the cheese should be allowed to warm up before being consumed.